# How solve this Partial Differential Equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solve $u_{tt}=u_{xx}+u_{yy}$; $u=u(x,y,t)$

I don't know how to solve this. I know that if  $u$ depend of two variables $(x,y)$ , i do the sustitution $u=f(x)\cdot g(y)$. But if $u$ depend of three $(x,y,t)$ variables can i do the sustitution $u=f(x) \cdot g(y) \cdot h(t)$?

Answer (score 1):

Regards. It may be more convenient to write $u(x,t)$ and $u(x,y,t)$, for 1D space and 2D space respectively. If you let
$u=F(x,y)G(t)$ you would get
$$u_{xx}=F_{xx} G$$
$$u_{yy}=F_{yy}G$$
$$u_{tt}=FG''(t)$$
and
$$FG''=G(F_{xx}+F_{yy})$$
by the PDE. Which is equivalent with
$$\frac{G''(t)}{G} = \frac{(F_{xx}+F_{yy})}{F}=\alpha \: \: \text{    (a constant)}$$
This is because left side is a function of $t$ only, while right side does not depend on $t$. You may continue from here. Thanks.